# Does not remove save data. if, I do uninstall module in Opencart 3

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart-3

I have update my theme module for OpenCart **3.0.2.0**. Normally this is working fine. but, does create one minor issue.

If, I does uninstall my custom theme module from admin(Extension>Extensions>Modules). though, Does not removed saved data from front side & admin side.
when, I will after again install & edit module. So, Does not remove above saved data. also, The saved data settings are not removed from the front. it does still save data.

this is working fine in older(2.3.0.2) version. But, Here, I can not judge. why this happen in latest version.
Can you please any suggestion? following code our file.

**mytheme.php** (admin\controller\extension\module)

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleMytheme extends Controller {

    private $error = array(); 

    public function index() {   

        $language = $this->load->language('extension/module/mytheme');
        $data = array_merge($language);

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        $this->load->model('setting/setting');

        $this->load->model('tool/image');  

        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
            $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('mytheme', $this->request->post);    

            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            if(isset($this->request->post['save_stay']) and $this->request->post['save_stay']=1)
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/module/mytheme', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], true));
            else
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('marketplace/extension', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&type=module', true));

        }

            $data['text_image_manager'] = 'Image manager';
            $data['user_token'] = $this->session->data['user_token'];       

        if (isset($this->session->data['success'])) {
            $data['success'] = $this->session->data['success'];
            unset($this->session->data['success']);
        } else {
            $data['success'] = '';
        }

        // store config data

        $config_data = array(

        'mytheme_background_color',
        'mytheme_button_color',
        'mytheme_powered_text',

        );

        foreach ($config_data as $conf) {
            if (isset($this->request->post[$conf])) {
                $data[$conf] = $this->request->post[$conf];
            } else {
                $data[$conf] = $this->config->get($conf);
            }
        }


        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], true)
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_extension'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('marketplace/extension', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&type=module', true)
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('extension/module/mytheme', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], true)
        );


        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('extension/module/mytheme', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'], true);

        $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('marketplace/extension', 'user_token=' . $this->session->data['user_token'] . '&type=module', true);

        if (isset($this->request->post['mytheme_module'])) {
            $modules = explode(',', $this->request->post['mytheme_module']);
        } elseif ($this->config->get('mytheme_module') != '') {
            $modules = explode(',', $this->config->get('mytheme_module'));
        } else {
            $modules = array();
        }           

        $this->load->model('localisation/language');

        $data['languages'] = $this->model_localisation_language->getLanguages();

        $data['modules'] = $modules;

        if (isset($this->request->post['mytheme_module'])) {
            $data['mytheme_module'] = $this->request->post['mytheme_module'];
        } else {
            $data['mytheme_module'] = $this->config->get('mytheme_module');

        }

        $data['mytheme_modules'] = array();

        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module/mytheme', $data));
    }

    protected function validate() {
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'extension/module/mytheme')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
        }

        return !$this->error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create uninstall function in your controller.

```
public function uninstall() {
      $this->load->model('setting/setting');
      $this->model_setting_setting->deleteSetting('mytheme');

}
```

You don't need to call this function. It will be auto call when you uninstall the module.

Best of luck. :)

Comment: working fine with your code. Thanks. but, one question, why does remove save data after uninstall other default module without this type code. have not use any this code in any other default module.

Comment: In previous (version of ) opencart ,  its auto call deleteSetting function during uninstall modules. But in this new version you need to call it yourself (in case you need to delete old data)

Don't forget to give vote for the answer, if this helped you. :) 
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks you so much.